# Can someone tell me what this c code is doing?

Tags: c, cython

Cansome tell me what is going in this cython code. Full code can be seen at:

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/spatial/ckdtree.pyx

```
# this is the standard trick for variable-size arrays:
# malloc sizeof(nodeinfo)+self.m*sizeof(double) bytes.
cdef struct nodeinfo:
    innernode* node
    double side_distances[0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an old C trick. If you don't know how many `side_distances` are needed, usually because it varies from one instance of `nodeinfo` to another, then you declare the array size zero. Then when you allocate the memory for the node, you allocate the size of the struct *as it was defined* (`sizeof(nodeinfo)`), plus extra memory for the number of values you want in that particular instance (`+something * sizeof(double)`). The result is that *for this instance*, we have enough memory for an array of the size we specified.

It's a "trick" in the sense that for most uses you could allocate a separate array and store a pointer to it in this array. Keeping everything in one allocation is an (attempted) optimization.

IIRC, though, the zero-sized array is only allowed by the C++ standard, not the C standard. In C, you should define it as a flexible-sized array `side_distances[]`, although no doubt many compilers permit the C++ version in C as an extension. Either way, though, the struct itself doesn't contain room for any elements, although it will be correctly aligned for `double`.

Answer (score 2):

That's the [`struct hack`](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StructHack) in C. I don't know how it behaves in Python (or cython), <s>but I think you're better off using some other data structure</s>.

What it is used for, in C, is to pretend to have a "variable sized array".
It needs dynamic allocation of memory though.

Comment: This is not OP's code. This is scipy. I don't see why you recommend using another data structure. Cython is a way of writing C code with Python syntax. Kind of wild! +1

Comment: You're right @David. I shouldn't suggest stuff about languages I'm not familiar with -- suggestion (kinda) removed.